# Is the order of integers mod p under multiplication output of Carmichael's function?

Tags: group-theory, carmichael-function

I've been trying to understand the [group theory proof of Fermat's little theorem](http://planetmath.org/proofoffermatslittletheoremusinglagrangestheorem).

Let's say there exists group $G = (ℤ/pℤ)^x$, and it has multiplicative subgroup $H$ (a monoid group, as i understand). The group $H$ is generated by some element $a$, this makes $H$ a cyclic group.

According to group theory, $|H|$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $a^k = e$ (where $e$ is identity) and considering that identity in multiplicative group is always $1$, we can assume that order of the subgroup $|H|$ is equal to output of Carmichael's function. Thus $a^k ≡ 1  
 mod(p)$.

Now as i understand, $|H|≡λ(p)$, if $H$ is multiplicative group, is this always a case? If so, why?

Comment: this is confusing.  Are you asking if, for composite $n$, we always have $\lambda (n) = |\,\left( \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\right)^*\,|$ or are you asking something else?

Comment: If I have interpreted your question properly (not at all clear) then you can read about the [Carmichael Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) to find many cases in which $\lambda (n)< \varphi(n)$.

Comment: @lulu According to the group theory, If is generated by some element $a$, the the order of $H$ is also the order of $a$. i.e it is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $a^k = e$ (where $e$ is identity, and as we know identity under multiplicative group is always 1), and thus $a^k = 1 mod (p)$, isn't this similar to Carmichael's function?

Comment: [This is the source from where i got this information](http://planetmath.org/proofoffermatslittletheoremusinglagrangestheorem).

Comment: Your question is a jumble.  You start with a prime modulus, for which the multiplicative group is cyclic.  Obviously in this case $\lambda (p)=\varphi (p)=p-1$, no problem.  Then you switch to $n$ but you don't tell us what $n$ is.  If it is meant to be composite, then you can not assume that $\left( \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \right)^*$ is cyclic, it isn't always.  So, please edit your post to make your assumptions and your question clearer.

Comment: @lulu Apologies, i'm beginner to group theories so i was not completely able to understand the source. I'l edit it right now.

Comment: @lulu I've fixed the question. What does totient function have to do with this? I know that according to Lagrange's theorem Euler's totient function happens to be multiple of Carmichael's function. But i'm just asking if $|H|≡λ(p)$ is true if $H$ is multiplicative group generated by $a$.

Comment: The header still refers to $n$ and you never actually say that $p$ is a prime, but let's take for granted that it is.  In that case, it is indeed true that $ \left( \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \right)^*$ is cyclic.  It has order $p-1$ of course and in this case it is certainly true (and somewhat obvious) that we also have $\lambda (p)=p-1$.   In general, $\varphi(n)$ is the order of $\left( \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \right)^*$ so here $\varphi(p)=p-1=\lambda (p)$.  However, this is not generally true if you replace $p$ with a composite number $n$.

Comment: @lulu So as i understand, this is one of the main points for existence of Carmichael's function? Thank you!